# Bar overlay filled scatter

Tags: javascript, plotly

Whenever I fill a scatter its drawn over the top of the bars on a multi chart type graph.

See example here
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXgNBG

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
  y: [1.5, 1, 1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9], 
  type: 'scatter',
  fill: 'tozeroy'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
  y: [1, 0.5, 0.7, -1.2, 0.3, 0.4], 
  type: 'bar'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

Any ideas how to draw the bars over the filled area on the scatter? I would like the bars drawn over the top of the filled area to make them stand out.